# 2048 move solver hitch; why are my variables being written over?

Tags: python

As a small project I decided to try and make a 2048 (game) player AI with minimax algorithms, but I have run in to a very confusing problem right off the bat.

In a certain part of the code, my variable (new_board_2) becomes replaced with another (new_board_1).

Part in question:

```
# Function that returns all possible boards after all possible moves (U,R,D,L)
# Currently under construction
def find_moves(board):
    return_list = []
    new_board_1 = board

    for repeat in range(3):
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(4):
                if not new_board_1[2-row][column]:
                    new_board_1[2-row][column] = new_board_1[3-row][column]
                    new_board_1[3-row][column] = []
    return_list.append(new_board_1)

    new_board_2 = board

    for repeat in range(3):
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(4):
                if not new_board_2[row + 1][column]:
                    new_board_2[row + 1][column] = new_board_2[row][column]
                    new_board_2[row][column] = []
    return_list.append(new_board_2)

    return return_list
```

The expected return from function find_moves is

> [new_board_1, new_board_2]

I am receiving

> [new_board_2, new_board_2]

With user input "0002000000400000" in reference to the entire project (see full code at bottom), my expected output to be printed to the console is:

> [ 0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   2 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> (blank)
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   2 ]

Printed to the console is:

> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   2 ]
>
> (blank)
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ]
>
> [ 0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   2 ]

Here is all of my code:

```
# 2048 best move calculator

game_board = [[[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []]]
possible_outcomes = []

# User imports board as a string of 16 chars (0002000000400000 e.g.)
starting_board_str = raw_input("What is your board?")

for number in range(16):
    game_board[number / 4][number % 4] = int(starting_board_str[number])


# Function that prints the board in a grid formation
def print_board(board):
    for row in range(4):
        for column in range(4):
            if not board[row][column]:
                board[row][column] = 0

    for row in range(len(board)):
        if row % 4 == 0:
            print ""
            print ""
        print " ".join(str(board[row]))
        print ""


# Function that returns all possible boards after all possible moves (U,R,D,L)
def find_moves(board):
    return_list = []
    new_board_1 = board

    for repeat in range(3):
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(4):
                if not new_board_1[2-row][column]:
                    new_board_1[2-row][column] = new_board_1[3-row][column]
                    new_board_1[3-row][column] = []
    return_list.append(new_board_1)

    new_board_2 = board

    for repeat in range(3):
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(4):
                if not new_board_2[row + 1][column]:
                    new_board_2[row + 1][column] = new_board_2[row][column]
                    new_board_2[row][column] = []
    return_list.append(new_board_2)

    return return_list


print_board(find_moves(game_board)[0])
```

Thank you in advance, and I'm sorry for any formatting issues... I'm new to stack overflow and welcome any constructive criticism!

Comment: why is `new_board_2` set to `board` if that is equal to `new_board_1`?

Comment: @FishingCode because I want to be able to change the boards individually before putting them together so I don't lose a copy of the original one. My thought process was, if I used 'board' I would have to somehow re-make the board to find out what would happen if moved left, or right, or down.